# Django Rest ModelSerializer Find or Create Pattern

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, view

I am new to Django. Reading a lot of ways to do the same thing--but not finding the proverbial needle in a haystack. One such needle is a simple "Find or Create" pattern for Django Rest.

I am trying to find a simple example of how to go about implementing a find or create pattern for one of my model data using Django Rest ModelSerializer and CreateAPIView methods. Let say that I have a model Location with a unique field 'address'. I want to return an existing instance when the address already exists on my database. If the address does not exist, I want to create an entry in the database and populate other computed values for the object.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True,)
    thing1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, )
    thing2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, )

    def compute_things(self, address):
        somevalue1 = ...
        somevalue2 = ....
        return somevalue1, somevalue2
```

Now, I am not exactly sure how to write the serializer and view so that:

1. A new location is created and returned with all the fields
   initialized when a new address is seen for the first time
2. An existing location that matches 'address' in the database is
   returned in lieu of step 1

What else should I define for the model? How do I write APIView and CreateSerializer to get the right thing? Where should I call the compute_thing() in order to populate the missing fields.

For the serializer:

```
class LocationCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

And for the APIView:

```
class LocationCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = LocationCreateSerializer
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
```

The APIView and Serializer above are not enough for what I need. What else do I need to add to model, View and Serializer to get that behavior that I am seeking?

I don't want the View nor the Serializer to return validation errors for duplicate 'addresses'--just the existing instance and not an error. It looks like restore_object() is deprecated. Is there a way to accomplish what I am seeking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the answer to my own question. I am not sure this is the best solution; however, for anyone that needs a solution, here is what I ended up doing:

```
class LocationCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = LocationCreateSerializer
    queryset = Location.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        address = None
        if 'address' in self.request.data:
            address = self.request.data['address']
        else:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(address=address)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(location)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        serializer = LocationCreateSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            somevalue1, somevalue2 = Location.compute_things(self, address=address)
            if (not somevalue1) | (not somevalue2):
                return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

            serializer.save(address=address, thing1=somevalue1, thing2=somevalue2)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

If you have a better solution, please post it. I'd like to continue learning.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one thing, that is,

`fields =("Here will be your models fields. That you want to serialize.")`
That is after the `model = Location` in serializer.

And you can follow official doc of `Django-REST-Framework`

Comment: The default fields, when 'fields' is not specified,  is all fields. This won't solve the problem.